# Does ActiveMQ Classic support "Detecting Failure from the Client"

Tags: connection, activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

We use ActiveMQ Classic 5.10 for our JMS broker. However we found the connection will be accumulated and sometimes reach to limit. We didn't find any connection leak problem in our code.
By using Google we found that there is a feature in ActiveMQ Artemis which named ["Detecting Failure from the Client"](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/connection-ttl.html), but we didn't find such feature in ActiveMQ Classic.

Can anyone tell me if is there a feature in ActiveMQ Classic just like "Detecting Failure from the Client" in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ 5.x broker has features to detect that a client has dropped, mainly in the form of heartbeat messages to the connected clients.  If you have changed the default configuration of the clients then it can become an issue for the broker to detect drops in a timely manner if the heartbeat intervals are set to large numbers.

It also depends a bit on the client you are using and the protocol it uses but most have some form of heart beating capability so you would need to investigate your clients and what configuration you are operating under.

5.10.0 is a very old broker release as well, upgrading to latest release will give you all the numerous bug fixes that have been done since that release.